# pyTelegramBotAPI search in text of the message with if/elif/else construction

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have question about behaviuor of pyTelegramBotAPI library with Python 3.6.5. It is a libray to work with Telegram API.

There is my code:

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message
from telebot import types

TOKEN = 'TOCKEN_HERE'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
itembtn_privet = types.KeyboardButton('If')
itembtn_more = types.KeyboardButton('Elif')
itembtn_else = types.KeyboardButton('Else')
markup.row(itembtn_privet, itembtn_more, itembtn_else)
bot.send_message(chat_id_here, "Choose one option:", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def command_handler(message: Message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'The is no answer, sorry(')


@bot.edited_channel_post_handler(content_types=['text'])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo_messages(message: Message):
    text = message.text
    if text == 'If' or 'if':
         bot.reply_to(message, 'If')
    elif text == 'Elif' or 'elif':
         bot.reply_to(message, f'Elif')
    else:
         bot.reply_to(message, 'Else')

bot.polling(timeout=60)
```

My question - I can choise any option, but qnswer always be "If". Why I can't manage answer with if/elif/else? How can I fix it? Do I need to use regexp (please no)?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple just change:

```
if text == 'If' or 'if':
```

to

```
if text == 'If':
```

Comment: `text == 'If' or 'if'` is equivalent to `(text == 'If') or 'if'`. If `text` does equal `'If'` that expression will result in `True` otherwise, it will result in `'if'`. So in either case, the `if` test will pass, since a non-empty string is considered to be true.

Comment: The usual way to do case-insensitive testing is like `if text.lower() == 'elif':`